# maven-assembly-plugin - how to enable module-by-module basis of processing project modules output directories

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to follow this guide: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html in order in order to create a project with following desired structure (after all building and packaging):

```
Parent
      `child1
      |      `target/child1-1.0.jar
      `child2
      |      `target/child2-1.0.jar
      `child3
      |      `target/child3-1.0.jar
      `distribution
      |            `target/distribution-1.0-bin/child1/child1-1.0.jar
      |            `target/distribution-1.0-bin/child2/child2-1.0.jar
      |            `target/distribution-1.0-bin/child3/child3-1.0.jar
      `src
          `assemble/bin.xml
```

The problem is: after packaging stage; assembly plugin flattening all `target/distribution-1.0-bin/childN/` directories into single `distribution` directory; which makes it look like this:

```
       distribution
                   `target/distribution-1.0-bin/distribution/child1-1.0.jar
                   `target/distribution-1.0-bin/distribution/child2-1.0.jar
                   `target/distribution-1.0-bin/distribution/child3-1.0.jar
```

How do i preven such flattening?

I am creating project with the following shellscript:

```
#!/bin/sh

# creating project root
mvn archetype:generate -D archetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -D archetypeArtifactId=pom-root -D groupId=org.test -D artifactId=parent -D version=1.0 -D package=org.test -D interactiveMode=false
cd parent/

# creating child modules
for i in 1 2 3; do mvn archetype:generate -D archetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -D archetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -D groupId=org.test -D artifactId=child${i} -D version=1.0 -D package=org.test -D interactiveMode=false; done

# creating distribution module
mvn archetype:generate -D archetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -D archetypeArtifactId=pom-root -D groupId=org.test -D artifactId=distribution -D version=1.0 -D package=org.test -D interactiveMode=false

# making dir for assemblies
mkdir src/assemble/ -p
```

; my Parent/src/assemble/bin.xml is token entirely unchanged from the [url mentioned above](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html) (The Assembly Descriptor section), as well as the Parent/pom.xml (The POM section, snippet #1) and my Parent/distribution/pom.xml token from The POM section, snippet #2 with only change adding missing `<plugins>` tags between `<build>` and `<plugin>` ones.

**EDIT1**

Okay, since i've been questioned about actual poms twice, here they are moved from [url](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html) and maven quicktype archetype to this page:

**`Parent/pom.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>Parent</name>

  <modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
    <module>child3</module>
    <module>distribution</module>
  </modules>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <descriptors>
              <descriptor>src/assemble/bin.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

**`Parnet/child1/pom.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>child1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

**`Parent/distribution/pom.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>distribution</artifactId>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>Distribution</name>

  <!-- NOTE: These dependency declarations are only required to sort this project to the 
       end of the line in the multimodule build. 

       Since we only include the child1 module in our assembly, we only need to ensure this
       distribution project builds AFTER that one...
  -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
<plugins> <!-- exception -->
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>distro-assembly</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <descriptors>
              <descriptor>src/assemble/bin.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins> <!-- exception -->
  </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT2**

And descriptor file as well:

**`Parent/src/assemble/bin.xml`**

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>bin</id>
  <formats>
    <format>dir</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>

      <!-- Enable access to all projects in the current multimodule build! -->
      <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

      <!-- Now, select which projects to include in this module-set. -->
      <includes>
        <include>org.test:child1</include>
      </includes>
      <binaries>
        <outputDirectory>modules/${artifactId}</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
      </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: First how does your pom for the child1..childN look like? How does the pom for the distribution look like? And why are you creating the projects via script? Furthermore the bin descriptor in your project looks like superfluous cause there exist already a predefined descriptor for this.

Comment: 1. childN descriptors are the default created by maven from quickstart archetype, as it does shellscript above; 2. distribution pom is looking exactly like in [url](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html) i posted; 3. i am creating it via script to help you reproduce environment i am having; 4. predefined descriptors are being referenced via `<descriptorRef>` tag, not via `<descriptor>` tag i am using.

Comment: I see that your descriptor contains a format which is not defined by the maven-assembly-plugin...What are you trying to achieve? Ah one thing. Why do you have located the bin descriptor in the parent instead into the distribution module ?

Comment: It **is** suported by maven-assembly-plugin, just look at documentation main page, section under "Currently it can create distributions in the following formats:" words: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/ . I am tryin to achive exactly whan manual i posted first is supposed to teach - create a properly layed out directory with jars from my entire multi-module project.

Comment: Placement of descriptor was chosen because it has project-wide meaning. Also, moving it from parent to distribution changes absolutely nothing, because of `<pluginManagement>` being used.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment, I think locating the assembly descriptor in the parent is not a good idea. By doing this, you deprive the distribution module from a part of its responsabilities (managing the global assembly)... Anyway, concerning your problem, can you explain why you simply don't use an 'hard-coded' path for the outputDirectory value of each moduleSet rather than '${artifactId}' (which, here, will obviously always give you  'distribution' as result) ?

Comment: Because i damn want it to be an ${artifactId} of my modules, as it should be according to documentation, not a "distribution" for every module i have.

Comment: The location of the assembly descriptor is assumed to be in the module which contains the execution of the appropriate plugin (maven-assembly-plugin) and not on a higher level which will not with this configuration. You should check the output with mvn -X ...to see what's happening.